# Proving an inequality using field order axioms only.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

In a very recent post I was trying to get guidance on how to prove that $x^2+x>0$ whenever $x<0$.
I didn't consider this doesn't hold if $x \in (-1,0)$.

However, what I'm really trying to prove is that $x^2+x+1>0$ for $x\in R$

I have considered the following:

i) If $x\geq0$, then $x^2\geq0$. This means $x^2 +x \geq0$, from which we get $x^2+x+1\geq1$. Hence $x^2+x+1\geq0$.

ii) If $x<0$, then $-x>0$, so $(-x)(-x)>0$, which means $x^2>0$. As $-x>0>x$, we also have that $x^2-x+1>x^2+1>x^2+x+1$

In this ii) part is where I'm struggling. I know that $(x+\frac{1}{2})= x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}\geq0$, so I could pretty much conclude from here $x^2+x+1>x^2+x+\frac{1}{4}\geq0$. However, I'm trying to prove this only with algebraic manipulation for the case $x<0$. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why insist on treating $x<0$ separately? It isn’t natural for this problem.

Just note that no matter what $x$ is, you have
$$x^2+x+1=x^2+x+\tfrac14-\tfrac14+1$$
$$=(x+\tfrac12)^2 +\tfrac34\geq\tfrac34>0$$

Comment: You're right. I guess I chose to consider two cases, because at first I wasn't using (x+1/2)^2 so I split it that way. I didn't really want to use the (x+1/2)^2 argument there. I mean, case i) is clearly shown without it, and I wanted to do the same for case ii), not sure if it can be done though.

Comment: This shows the graph of $y=x^2+x+1$ is a parabola opening upwards, with its lowest point (the vertex) at $(-\tfrac12,\tfrac34)$. So all values of $x^2+x+1$ are no less than $\tfrac34$.

Comment: I understand that, but the focus is on using the field order axioms, not parabolas neither graphs. That's why I'm saying, that not using the $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2$ argument, but starting only from the fact that $x<0$ in case ii), and proceeding with these axioms.